# Storing HTML Documents in Elasticsearch

Tags: html, elasticsearch

#### Scenario

I have HTML documents, let's say: emails. I want to store these on elastic search and search the plaintext of HTML emails.

#### Problem

Elasticsearch would index all the HTML tags and attributes, too. I don't want that. I want to search for `span` if it is a plain text, not a html element. For example `<span>span</span>` could be a hit, but not `<span>some other content</span>`.

#### Question

Would you recommend, to store a HTML stripped field and a HTML field in a document? Or should I store the HTML document on S3 and rather leave a stripped HTML version in elastic search? Does it even make sense

I honestly don't know what happens if elastic search is indexing a HTML document, but I could imagine that it will also index divs and spans and all the attributes. These are things I totally don't search for. So: any suggestion on solving the problem here would be great!

#### What am I doing now?

Right now before I store a document in ES, I check if the index exists for the document type. If not, I create a collection with a given mapping. The mapping looks like this

```
{
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "htmlStripAnalyzer": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": "standard",
                "char_filter": [
                    "html_strip"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "${type}": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "_metadata": {
                        "path_match": "_metadata.*",
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "properties": {
                "_tags": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "dynamic": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Warning: Ignore the existing mappings. It has nothing to do with my intentions. They are just there.*

I am replacing ${type} with the document type, let's say `emails`.
**What would it look like to tell ES to not index the HTML stuff?**

Comment: You probably want to define a static mapping to index only the relevant fields regarding your HTML documents, and probably a way to retrieve your document (the path, or an id allowing you to compute the said path). Here is a little more on mapping from Elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

Comment: @asettouf I edited the question. You may see what I'm doing now.

Comment: I see, basically `dynamic` should be set to false (or strict), and you will have to provide explicitly what interests you to index in the document. That means that you will have to parse the HTML, and then construct a JSON query (yourself or through the ES API) to feed ES only the relevant part. I can write a small example if you are interested

Comment: I'd love to see an example - because I still don't get what you mean. Just to mention, I'm a bloody beginner with ES.

Comment: I don't get it. What's the connection between the mapping you posted and your desired outcome? I don't see the analyzer used anywhere, instead I see a dynamic template. What's your intent?

Comment: If I'm not missing anything you simply do `"properties":{"_tags":{"type":"nested","dynamic":true},"html":{"type":"text","analyzer":"htmlStripAnalyzer"}}` and that's it.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Ignore the existing mappings. It has nothing to do with my intentions. They are just there. But I'll checkout the solution you provided in the other comment

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A complete test case:

```
DELETE /test
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "htmlStripAnalyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": ["lowercase"],
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "html": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "htmlStripAnalyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /test/test/1
{
  "html": "<td><tr>span<td></tr>"
}
POST /test/test/2
{
  "html": "<span>whatever</span>"
}
POST /test/test/3
{
  "html": "<html> <body> <h1 style=\"font-family: Arial\">Test</h1> <span>More test</span> </body> </html>"
}

POST /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "html": "span"
    }
  }
}

POST /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "html": "body"
    }
  }
}

POST /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "html": "more"
    }
  }
}
```

#### Update for Elasticsearch >=7 ([removal of types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html))

```
DELETE /test
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "htmlStripAnalyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": ["lowercase"],
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "html": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "htmlStripAnalyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /test/_doc/1
{
  "html": "<td><tr>span<td></tr>"
}
POST /test/_doc/2
{
  "html": "<span>whatever</span>"
}
POST /test/_doc/3
{
  "html": "<html> <body> <h1 style=\"font-family: Arial\">Test</h1> <span>More test</span> </body> </html>"
}

POST /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "html": "span"
    }
  }
}

POST /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "html": "body"
    }
  }
}

POST /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "html": "more"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that this also strips out relevant content for `<img>` tags inside the `title` and `alt` attributes. So not great for webpage searching. Example: `<img src="/beach.jpg" title="My favorite beach picture" />` would be removed completely and not match queries for `beach`

Comment: What is the purpose of adding the "lowercase" filter? Also, this needs to updated slightly against Elasticsearch 7.6.

Comment: @mbroshi, the 'standard' analyzer is comprised (in it's simplest form) of the 'standard' tokenizer and the 'lowercase' filter (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html#_definition_4), so this is the base for the custom 'htmlStripAnalizer' above.

Comment: Note, in newer versions of elasticsearch you need to change the mappings definitions like this: `"mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "html": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "htmlStripAnalyzer"
      }
    }
  }
`
You must remove the  `"html":` part.

Answer (score 1):

By default Elasticsearch will dynamically add new fields if it finds any during the indexing process (see [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/dynamic-mapping.html)):

> When Elasticsearch encounters a previously unknown field in a document, it uses dynamic mapping to determine the datatype for the field and automatically adds the new field to the type mapping.

To disable this behavior (see the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html) for more details), the simplest is to put `dynamic` to *false* (prevents the automatic creation) or to *strict* (throws an exception and does not create a new document). In that case, you would need to explicitly write the mapping for the tags you wish to keep inside your `_tags` section, and pre parse the HTML document to only feed the tags you are interested in to Elasticsearch.

So let's say you have the following HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>A simple example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <p><span class="ref">A sentence I want to reference from this HTML document</span></p>
    <p><span class="">Something less important</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The first thing you want to have is a static mapping inside Elasticsearch, I would do the following (assuming the ref is a string):

```
PUT html
{

"mappings": {
  "test":{
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {
      "ref":{
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now if you try adding a document this way, it will succeed:

```
PUT html/test/1
{
  "ref": "A sentence I want to reference from this HTML document"
}
```

But this won't succeed:

```
PUT html/test/2
{
  "ref": "A sentence I want to reference from this HTML document",
  "some_field": "Some field"
}
```

Now the only thing remaining is to parse the HTML to retrieve the "ref" field, and create the above query (use whatever language you like, Java, Python...)

**Edit:** Actually to store the HTML without indexing it, in your mapping you simply need to set `index` to no (see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2)):

```
"_tags": {
          "type": "nested",
          "dynamic": true,
          "index": "no"
         }
```

Comment: Well yeah. Thanks for your good explanation, this also helped me out.
I can strip HTML with Java aswell, but I wanted to have the original HTML document to be stored in elastic search (to view it later). But I don't want it to index all the HTML contents. So basically, I have to tell ES not to index all the HTML stuff. You got it?

Comment: @BlackHat Got it, simply set `index` to no then, and put the other fields you want to index into different properties. See my edit.

Comment: I better make things clear. I want to store the whole HTML document with all its HTML tags in ES. And I want to retrieve the HTML document when I search for it. But I don't want to find the HTML document when I search for "span" as example.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @AmazingTurtle I need the same things - save original HTML, to show the position of search results. how did you solve it eventually?

Comment: @Lior Tbh, I think you should parse first the HTML with a scrapper, then send that result to logstash any way you want